# Ship external javascript library with own angular 6 component library

Tags: angular, angular6

I am building an Angular 6 component library that will be published privately on Github. It's aim is to be used in several other projects. This means that this library will be installed via npm and then the components should be imported from this library.
Thus, the components do not have any index.html.
It is quite common to import javascript libraries, say OpenStreetMap, by adding the following in the index.html of the angular project:

```
<script src=""></script>
```

I'm looking for a way to still "shipping" these external CDN links with my component library. I don't want to download this file and just put it as extra file in the component folder, since potential updates could be important.

Is there any way to make this work?